# Expectation of inverse of complex Gaussian variables

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, expectation

If we consider a complex Gaussian random variable as $h\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is the variance. Is there any closed-form solution with $\gamma$ for $\mathbf{E}\left[\frac{1}{\lVert h\rVert_2^2}\right]$? where $\lVert\cdot\rVert^2$ denotes the norm-$2$ operation.

Really appreciate for any comments!

Comment: Seems to be just $+\infty$ . . . the double integral of $1/|z|^2$ diverges logarithmically near $z=0$.

Comment: The modulus of $h$ is an explonential random variable.

Comment: I don't think so it would be positive infinity. Just to imagine the average normalized mean square error: $\mathbb{E}\frac{||a-b||^2}{||a||^2}$, it should be converge to some value

Comment: Here at CV https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564326/expected-value-of-inverse-random-variable-with-norm-of-multivariate-normal   is the same question, but the real-valued case,. with links to a complete solution

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies said it all, but just to write this explicitly: $$\mathbf{E}\left[\frac{1}{\|h\|_2^2}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,(\pi\gamma)^{-1}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/\gamma}(x^2+y^2)^{-1}$$ $$=(2/\gamma)\int_0^\infty dr\, e^{-r^2/\gamma} r^{-1}=\infty.$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, since you [edited](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/436733/2) `|| ||` to `\| \|`—definitely an improvement—you might like to know about `\lVert \rVert`, which is semantically preferable.  (For example, $\|-x\|$ `\|-x\|` spaces poorly compared to $\lVert-x\rVert$ `\lVert-x\rVert`.)  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice is this equivalent to `\left\|` and `\right\|` ?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436733/expectation-of-inverse-of-complex-gaussian-variables#comment1125930_436733), basically, but without sizing. (It's probably close to `\mathopen\| \mathclose\|`.) Compare $\lVert{\displaystyle\sum}\rVert$ `\lVert{\displaystyle\sum}\rVert` to $\left\|{\displaystyle\sum}\right\|$ `\left\|{\displaystyle\sum}\right\|`.

Comment: Thank you guys all for your comments. What if now I change the question into: the Gaussian complex $\textbf{vector}$ $\mathbf{h}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times 1}$ that has n random variables $h$, then will the $\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{||\mathbf{h}||^2}$ still be infinity?

Comment: @CharlieNie --- for $n$ complex random variables the integrand over the radial coordinate $r$ varies as $r^{2n-3}$, so the integral is finite for $n>1$.

Comment: @LSpice : I've noticed a number of delimiters space badly when `\left` and `\right` are not used. Sometimes absolute values have that extra space before the unary plus or minus sign until `\left` and `\right` are used.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you for your answer and explanation!